# Redis get keys for sorted sets where at least one member has score less than N

Tags: lua, redis

I Have multiple sorted sets in my redis. The keys of them have the following pattern:

```
user:{userId}:data
```

where userId is the actual value.
Each member of the corresponding set has score equals to the timestamp when it was added.
Now I'm trying to figure out how can I retrieve redis keys for those sorted sets where at least one member was added before a certain timestamp (meaning that at least one member has score less than given timestamp in millis).

I can retrieve all the keys by pattern:

```
KEYS 'user:*:data'
```

Actually, I can check required condition for one key using command:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE user:{userId}:data -inf {timestamp}
```

and then checking size of returned data

But do I have any way (either one-line, or piping commands, or with Lua script) to get only those keys of sorted sets where at least one of the elements has lower score than given?

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid `KEYS`, or `SCAN`, if this query is important (i.e. needs to return fast). Instead, keep another sorted sets with the earliest timestamp each user has, and query it.